# Navigate from follow up intent to parent intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have follow up intent as follow. Note that intent A and intent B is on same node.
How can i exit and jump from intent E to intent A and intent B respectively? Seems that it can be done with `dialog-fulfillment` but I cannot figure out.

```
Intent A
Intent B
  - Intent C
    - Intent D
      - Intent E - A
      - Intent E - B (jump back to intent B)
      - Intent E - C (jump back to intent A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remember that Intents represent *what the user says or does* and not how you respond to that. So it doesn't make sense to say that you want to "jump to" another Intent - the user needs to trigger that Intent somehow.

If you want to respond the same way as those Intents - then use fulfillment for each to call the same function and respond the same way for each. This may require you to clear the Contexts that were set as part of the Followup intents.